# Fatal error: Interface 'Zend\Config\Reader\ReaderInterface'

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks, xmlreader

```
<?php
require_once BLOCKS_ROOT_ENGINE . "Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php";
//require_once BLOCKS_ROOT_ENGINE."library/Zend/Config/Reader/Xml.php";

class Engine {
    static public function start() {
        $autoLoader = new Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader(array(
            'fallback_autoloader' => true,
        ));
        // register our StandardAutoloader with the SPL autoloader
        $autoLoader->register();


        $config = new Engine_Zend_Config_Reader_Xml();
        //echo $config->config->layout->default->head;
        $root = new Core_Root_Blocks_Root();
    }
}
```

The above is located in `Engine/Engine.php`

The Zend library is located in `Engine/Zend/*` The autoloader successfully finds the Xml class. But for some strange reason it can not find the interface it implements. what am i doing wrong.

## Directory Structure

[image]

## XML.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Zend Framework (http://framework.zend.com/)
 *
 * @link      http://github.com/zendframework/zf2 for the canonical source repository
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2005-2013 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license   http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd New BSD License
 */

namespace Zend\Config\Reader;

use XMLReader;
use Zend\Config\Exception;

/**
 * XML config reader.
 */
class Xml implements ReaderInterface
{
    /**
     * XML Reader instance.
     *
     * @var XMLReader
     */
    protected $reader;

    /**
     * Directory of the file to process.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $directory;

    /**
     * Nodes to handle as plain text.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $textNodes = array(
        XMLReader::TEXT,
        XMLReader::CDATA,
        XMLReader::WHITESPACE,
        XMLReader::SIGNIFICANT_WHITESPACE
    );

    /**
     * fromFile(): defined by Reader interface.
     *
     * @see    ReaderInterface::fromFile()
     * @param  string $filename
     * @return array
     * @throws Exception\RuntimeException
     */
    public function fromFile($filename)
    {
        if (!is_file($filename) || !is_readable($filename)) {
            throw new Exception\RuntimeException(sprintf(
                "File '%s' doesn't exist or not readable",
                $filename
            ));
        }

        $this->reader = new XMLReader();
        $this->reader->open($filename, null, LIBXML_XINCLUDE);

        $this->directory = dirname($filename);

        set_error_handler(
            function ($error, $message = '', $file = '', $line = 0) use ($filename) {
                throw new Exception\RuntimeException(sprintf(
                    'Error reading XML file "%s": %s',
                    $filename, $message
                ), $error);
            }, E_WARNING
        );
        $return = $this->process();
        restore_error_handler();

        return $return;
    }

    /**
     * fromString(): defined by Reader interface.
     *
     * @see    ReaderInterface::fromString()
     * @param  string $string
     * @return array|bool
     * @throws Exception\RuntimeException
     */
    public function fromString($string)
    {
        if (empty($string)) {
            return array();
        }
        $this->reader = new XMLReader();

        $this->reader->xml($string, null, LIBXML_XINCLUDE);

        $this->directory = null;

        set_error_handler(
            function ($error, $message = '', $file = '', $line = 0) {
                throw new Exception\RuntimeException(sprintf(
                    'Error reading XML string: %s',
                    $message
                ), $error);
            }, E_WARNING
        );
        $return = $this->process();
        restore_error_handler();

        return $return;
    }

    /**
     * Process data from the created XMLReader.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function process()
    {
        return $this->processNextElement();
    }

    /**
     * Process the next inner element.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function processNextElement()
    {
        $children = array();
        $text     = '';

        while ($this->reader->read()) {
            if ($this->reader->nodeType === XMLReader::ELEMENT) {
                if ($this->reader->depth === 0) {
                    return $this->processNextElement();
                }

                $attributes = $this->getAttributes();
                $name       = $this->reader->name;

                if ($this->reader->isEmptyElement) {
                    $child = array();
                } else {
                    $child = $this->processNextElement();
                }

                if ($attributes) {
                    if (!is_array($child)) {
                        $child = array();
                    }

                    $child = array_merge($child, $attributes);
                }

                if (isset($children[$name])) {
                    if (!is_array($children[$name]) || !array_key_exists(0, $children[$name])) {
                        $children[$name] = array($children[$name]);
                    }

                    $children[$name][] = $child;
                } else {
                    $children[$name] = $child;
                }
            } elseif ($this->reader->nodeType === XMLReader::END_ELEMENT) {
                break;
            } elseif (in_array($this->reader->nodeType, $this->textNodes)) {
                $text .= $this->reader->value;
            }
        }

        return $children ?: $text;
    }

    /**
     * Get all attributes on the current node.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getAttributes()
    {
        $attributes = array();

        if ($this->reader->hasAttributes) {
            while ($this->reader->moveToNextAttribute()) {
                $attributes[$this->reader->localName] = $this->reader->value;
            }

            $this->reader->moveToElement();
        }

        return $attributes;
    }
}
```

## ERROR

[image]

Comment: So you're saying the class `Engine_Zend_Config_Reader_Xml` is successfully autoloaded but the ZF interface it implements is not? Can you provide a little more info about the file structure of your app along with what folder(s) you have on the include path?

Comment: @TimFountain Hey tim, thanks for the response, I am not at the computer but I will get that information to you asap. As of right now, the answer I can give you is Yes. The error I am getting is it can not find the Interface class that the Reader_Xml implements

Comment: I've provided more details including error messge and directory structure

Comment: Have you tried using `$loader->registerNamespace('Reader')` inside your `bootstrap.php` instead of using `namespace`?

Comment: Can you post the first part of the `Engine_Zend_Config_Reader_Xml` class as well?

Comment: yea when I get home, I will post that information asap

Answer (score 1):

I think that you missed to set the include paths to Zend Framework library in your `index.php` file.

The autoloader class loads because you add `require_once` to the exact file with autoloader class definition. As I understand `BLOCKS_ROOT_ENGINE` constant is defined in your `index.php`.

Also I guess that you add somehow `/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/blocks` path to include paths in `index.php` - that is because autoloader is able to load `Engine_Zend_Config_Reader_Xml` class.

It is necessary to add `BLOCKS_ROOT_ENGINE` in your `index.php` to include paths list to allow autoloader find `Zend\Config\Reader\ReaderInterface`.

Comment: BLOCKS_ROOT_ENGINE is inside index.php

Comment: what other include paths do I have to set to get this thing working

Comment: @numerical25 Please, add the contents of your `index.php` to your post

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your case, but once I ran into strange issues with my students with permission.
One student (with root permission) did something with folder permissions and we were not able to find out what - but files in that folder couldn't be accessible by php any more.

Even **file_exists()** returned false.
We finnaly resolve issue by copying whole folder, removing original one and renaming copied folder with original name.

Please check if your permissions are ok.

Answer (score 0):

Well the issue had to do with out I set up my autoloader. I downloaded the skeleton ZF2 and found this file that was quite helpful for setting up

```
<?php
/**
 * Zend Framework (http://framework.zend.com/)
 *
 * @link      http://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication for the canonical source repository
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2005-2013 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license   http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd New BSD License
 */

/**
 * This autoloading setup is really more complicated than it needs to be for most
 * applications. The added complexity is simply to reduce the time it takes for
 * new developers to be productive with a fresh skeleton. It allows autoloading
 * to be correctly configured, regardless of the installation method and keeps
 * the use of composer completely optional. This setup should work fine for
 * most users, however, feel free to configure autoloading however you'd like.
 */

// Composer autoloading
if (file_exists('vendor/autoload.php')) {
    $loader = include 'vendor/autoload.php';
}

$zf2Path = false;

if (is_dir('vendor/ZF2/library')) {
    $zf2Path = 'vendor/ZF2/library';
} elseif (getenv('ZF2_PATH')) {      // Support for ZF2_PATH environment variable or git submodule
    $zf2Path = getenv('ZF2_PATH');
} elseif (get_cfg_var('zf2_path')) { // Support for zf2_path directive value
    $zf2Path = get_cfg_var('zf2_path');
}

if ($zf2Path) {
    if (isset($loader)) {
        $loader->add('Zend', $zf2Path);
    } else {
        include $zf2Path . '/Zend/Loader/AutoloaderFactory.php';
        Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory::factory(array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'autoregister_zf' => true
            )
        ));
    }
}

if (!class_exists('Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory')) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Unable to load ZF2. Run `php composer.phar install` or define a ZF2_PATH environment variable.');
}
```